# Android Gallery Video Picker Intent not working correctly

Tags: android, video, android-intent, gallery

This almost exact same code works fine for selecting images but when selecting videos from a video view, it goes through a loop before it finally inserts the video. I may have to select it 7 times and it will keep returning to the gallery screen and I select it again, multiple times.  Sometimes I will back press out of the gallery and it will insert the video, but the code doesn't seem to know it has selected the image as the toast I have written for errors will play along side the video.  The runtime permissions have been written. This was tested on Android Marshmallow and Android Jellybean. I have tried using Action.GET_CONTENT and ACTION.PICK but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
vView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                 @Override
                 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                     videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                     videoIntent.setType("video/*");
                     checkIntent();// run-time permissions and intent checking //
                     startActivityForResult(videoIntent, RESULT_SHOW_VIDEO);

                     return true;
                 }
             });
         }
```

and the result handling code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RESULT_SHOW_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        chosenVideo = data.getData();
        videoView.setVideoURI(chosenVideo);
        videoView.start();
        newVidBtn.setEnabled(true)

// to get the path to store //
        String[] videoPath = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(chosenVideo, videoPath, null, null, null);
         if (cursor!= null) {
             cursor.moveToFirst();
             int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(videoPath[0]);
             vidString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
             cursor.close();
         }
    } else if(resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't load this video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        newVidBtn.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

If you understand why this is happening and how to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated.The other questions like this were answered with adding runtime permissions or they were not answered.

Comment: Pretty much everything in your `onActivityResult()` is wrong. You are assuming that you are getting a `Uri` back from the `MediaStore`. That is not a safe assumption.

Comment: wow that was a fast response! Thanks. I will look again at my onActivityResult code.  But it does produce the video...eventually.

Comment: Only by the way you happen to be using it as a user. What if the user chooses a video from something else that supports `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` that is not the `MediaStore`. Dropbox? Google Drive? Whatever problem you are trying to solve with your `query()` call needs to be addressed in some other fashion.

Comment: Oh I do see what you are saying. However what if I restrict the options of where selections can be made from to external storage only, would it not loop in that case?

Comment: "However what if I restrict the options of where selections can be made from to external storage only" -- how are you planning on doing that? If you only want files, [use a file picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35). Your *users* might wonder why they cannot use cloud providers with your app, but that's between you and your users.